# Convex optimization - matlab - 4D optimization variable

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization

In matlab optimization toolbox, is it possible for the optimization variable to be a 4D matrix and if so, how do I specify the start point? Can I just give it as all zeros? By 4D matrix, I mean a matrix of a matrices. Thus 4 indices are needed to fix a value.

Answer (score 0):

After working on it for a month, I have concluded that it is not possible. It has to be circumvented by changing the operations involved to accommodate a 1D vector which has to be interpreted as:

```
a1b1c1d1,a1b1c1d2,a1b1c2d1,a1b1c2d2,....
```

My point is that the vector contains all the data and there are *innermost* and *outermost* variables along with the intermediate ones. The matrix operations have to be designed to accommodate this.

Comment: why not? Have you looked at `fmincon`?